# React-Router activeSytle got error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using a sidebar with React-Router, and now I want to display the active sidebar icon like its mentioned here:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links

so I do this:

```
<li><Link to="/" className="fa fa-bars fa-2x" activeStyle="activeSidebar" aria-hidden="true"></Link></li>
```

But in Console I got this error:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `activeStyle` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see 
    in a (created by Link)
    in Link (at index.js:59)
    in li (at index.js:59)
    in ul (at index.js:58)
    in div (at index.js:57)
    in div (at index.js:56)
    in div (at index.js:55)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:54)
```

What could be the reason for this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You probably need activeClassName, not activeStyle

Comment: Got a similar errror: Warning: Unknown prop `activeClassName` on <a> tag.

Comment: Are you using version 4 of react-router? You should use NavLink this case in order to access these properties (see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activeClassName isn't a property you can pass to `<Link>`. However, it is a property that you can pass to `<NavLink>`. Switch out your `<Link>` component with `<NavLink>` and it should "just work". You can see the . full documentation for NavLink [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink). The reason NavLink exists and that functionality isn't on Link is because we wanted to keep Link lean and only provide the absolute necessary functionality in order to render an anchor tag.